# VBA macro only processing one if statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro here that will copy and paste data from primary spreadsheets to sub-spreadsheets, if a certain cell contains "Y".  Below is just a piece of the macro I'm putting together but I'm having some trouble with one thing.  The macro will copy and paste for only the first set it finds (i.e. the first "Y").

For example I have these two lines in the code:

```
If Range("G5") = "Y" Then
If Range("G9") = "Y" Then
```

If G5 is "Y" and G9 is "Y", only the G5 spreadsheets will populate.  However, if G5 is "N" and G9 is "Y" then G9 spreadsheets will populate.  I can get one to work but not both.  If it makes any difference I actually have 5 main spreadsheets but I wanted to keep the code shorter so it's not as difficult to follow.  I appreciate any help on this.

```
Sub Foo5()

Dim paa As Workbook
Dim pab As Workbook

Dim pa As Workbook
Dim pb As Workbook
Dim pc As Workbook
Dim pd As Workbook
Dim pe As Workbook
Dim pf As Workbook
Dim pg As Workbook
Dim ph As Workbook

Dim vals As Variant

If Range("G5") = "Y" Then

'Open workbooks and remove popups:
Set paa = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks("CF macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J5").Value, UpdateLinks:=0)
Set pa = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks("CF macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J6").Value, UpdateLinks:=0)
Set pb = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks("CF macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J7").Value, UpdateLinks:=0)
Set pc = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks("CF macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J8").Value, UpdateLinks:=0)

'Store the main cell value in a variable:
vals = paa.Sheets("Processed Summary").Range("M5:M63").Value

'Use the variable to assign the value to the sub cells:
pa.Sheets("Processed Summary").Range("L5:L63").Value = vals
pb.Sheets("Processed Summary").Range("L5:L63").Value = vals
pc.Sheets("Processed Summary").Range("L5:L63").Value = vals
End If

'Close Workbooks:
'paa.Close
'pa.Close
'pb.Close
'pc.Close

If Range("G9") = "Y" Then

'Open workbooks and remove popups:
Set pab = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks("CF macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J9").Value, UpdateLinks:=0)
Set pd = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks("CF macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J10").Value, UpdateLinks:=0)
Set pe = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks("CF macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J11").Value, UpdateLinks:=0)
Set pf = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks("CF macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J12").Value, UpdateLinks:=0)
Set pg = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks("CF macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J13").Value, UpdateLinks:=0)
Set ph = Workbooks.Open(Workbooks("CF macro.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J14").Value, UpdateLinks:=0)

'Store the main cell value in a variable:
vals = pab.Sheets("Processed Summary").Range("M5:M63").Value

'Use the variable to assign the value to the sub cells:
pd.Sheets("Processed Summary").Range("L5:L63").Value = vals
pe.Sheets("Processed Summary").Range("L5:L63").Value = vals
pf.Sheets("Processed Summary").Range("L5:L63").Value = vals
pg.Sheets("Processed Summary").Range("L5:L63").Value = vals
ph.Sheets("Processed Summary").Range("L5:L63").Value = vals
End If

'Close Workbooks:
'pab.Close
'pd.Close
'pe.Close
'pf.Close
'pg.Close
'ph.Close

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the if statements aren't nested inside each other?  If they were then the second if statement would only happen if you were inside the first.  The example code in your question doesn't do this but it's probably worth checking your real code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code could be condensed a lot using loops, and further if your actions are as consistent as they seem to be (always the same logic and ranges to be copied).

Also helps to be very specific about what sheets you're working with - your code should never have any call to `Range()` or `Cells()` which isn't qualified with a specific sheet reference.

EDIT: re-worked the "flag" range and condensed to a single sub.

Eg:

```vb
Sub Foo5()
    Const SHT_NAME As String = "Processed Summary"
    Dim arr, rngFlag As Range, el
    Dim wbSource As Workbook, wsConfig As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, rngSrc As Range
    
    Set wsConfig = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'all source range addresses in an array
    arr = Array("A5:A8", "A9:A14", "A15:A18", "A19:A24", "A25:A33", "A34:A37", _
                "A38:A43", "A44:A47", "A48:A53", "A54:A62", "A63:A66", "A67:A72", _
                "A73:A76", "A77:A82", "A83:A91")
    
    Set rngFlag = wsConfig.Range("I1")     'first "flag" cell
    
    For Each el In arr                     'loop over the array of range addresses
        If rngFlag.Value = "Y" Then        'process this block?
            Set rng = wsConfig.Range(el)   'get the range of workbook names/paths
            Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(rng.Cells(1).Value, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set rngSrc = wbSource.Worksheets(SHT_NAME).Range("M5:M63")
            For i = 2 To rng.Cells.Count
                With Workbooks.Open(rng.Cells(i).Value, UpdateLinks:=0)
                    .Worksheets(SHT_NAME).Range("L5:L63").Value = rngSrc.Value
                    .Close SaveChanges:=True
                End With
            Next i
            wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False 
        End If
        Set rngFlag = rngFlag.Offset(1) 'next cell down
    Next el
End Sub
```

Comment: This works great - thank you very much.  I'm still trying to figure out how to setup loops, which is why I'm still writing stuff in a less efficient method.

Comment: By the way I the actions are very consistent.  Really the only differences are: G5 references J5:J8, G9 to J9:J14, G15 to J15:J18, G19 to J19:J24, G25 to J25:33.... and this repeats two more times but with F5 to I5:I8 and E5 to H5:H8 and so on.  Your code works perfect for what I need though.  I'm just going to copy and paste it 18 times and then just edit the cell references.

Comment: See update above - you only need to call `DoCopies` and that will handle all the logic...

Comment: That's an awesome trick.  I'm still trying to figure out some of the logic.  I made a few changes to my spreadsheet to try to make the readability easier (I edited this post with your recommendation).  One issue I'm having with this update is it seems to only work with "Y" in the first row, so if column "I" looks something like this: N N N Y N Y Y Y N N, nothing will update, but if it looks like this: Y N N Y N Y then the first copy and paste range will work but not the others.  Hopefully that makes sense.  I'm having a hard time explaining/understanding this.

Comment: I will post and update.  FYI it's best if you don't completely replace your original question with new code based on an answer - I can follow well enough from your description in the comment.

Comment: This works perfect.  Thank you so much for your help and even writing out the full code!  It's very helpful to see the efficient version of what I'm looking to do so I can learn from better practices.  Also, point taken on the editing of original question.